# Ghost transactions ios storekit

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, storekit

I have a strange problem with iOS ans it's storekit library. This is something I can hardly reproduce myself but I can see it's happening to our clients (sometimes, most purchases work fine).

This is how it looks in our system
https://i.stack.imgur.com/pBhXi.png
[image: ghost transactions]

You can see one user reporting 4 transactions in timespan of few seconds. Only one of them has an actual transaction ID. Sometimes all those transactions have ID, sometime some of those IDs repeat. Complete randomness.

One of our programmers got this error once and what he reported (before it stopped happening for him) was that after pressing "buy" he got 4 or more transactions instead of one. Moreover those transactions skipped "purchasing" state and showed up as "purchased" instantly.

I can confirm that as none of those transactions show up in iTunes connect.

Do you have any ideas for why this may happen?

Comment: Please share the image on here as some of us can't access dropbox from where we are.

Comment: You cant just click this link and see it?

Comment: I am sure my last comment covered that **some of us CAN'T access dropbox from where we are** Questions that have images should include the image in the question not link out to another resource.

Comment: I embedded it in post.

Comment: You're making us do a lot of effort to help you out (Which isn't good as I am getting bored) Please make image bigger.

Comment: There is a stack link above it. Cant fit a bigger image inside a post